# Clojure and JAVA nio package,

Tags: java, clojure, path, nio

I wrote a very simple quick test a using java nio package.

```
(def cdr-incoming-dir (java.nio.file.Path/get (java.net.URI. "E:/path/to/random/data/")))
```

I get the error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching method: get (NO_SOURCE_FILE:211)
```

If I'm not mistaken the class Path has a static method called get which is overloaded. One of these versions static method takes a uri as an argument the other one takes two stings. I have tried both and both have failed what have I done wrong?

Very frustrating! 
Using clojure 1.1 and java jdk1.701 on windows 7.

Comment: It's beyond me and beyond my control.  But is my syntax not correct.

Comment: Have you looked at the Path [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html)? There doesn't appear to be a 'get' method in this interface.

Comment: I think you're looking for Paths.get(), not Path.get()

Comment: That's what led me to think I was using the correct version of java downloaded the newest one and still nothing.  The class Def exists or I would have gotten a different error.

Comment: The class (interface) 'Path' exists. The method doesn't.

Comment: Well that's embarrassing! I am now sure I'm to tired to write anymore code.

Comment: You can take a look at this wrapper library https://github.com/ToBeReplaced/nio.file

Answer (score 4):

As Alex mentions, you probably have a typo in the question. I think you're looking for Paths/get, not Path/get.

The docs for Paths/get say:

```
get(String first, String... more)
```

The second argument to Paths/get is a variadic string. Internally, this is actually a String array.

You should be able to use one of:

```
(java.nio.file.Paths/get "E:/path/to/random/data/" (make-array String 0))
(java.nio.file.Paths/get "E:/path/to/random/data/" (into-array String []))
(java.nio.file.Paths/get "E:/path/to/random/data/" (into-array [""]))
```

Comment: The specifying of  variadic arrays as java arguments was not obvious.